# globals() works only for the current module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, global-variables

By `globals()` I can see symbols in the current module. When I import another module, I can't see them. So how can I access a global class in another module by its name via `globals()` or however it's possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?  There might be a better way of achieving what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `globals()` only ever shows the current module namespace.

Modules are [objects with attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#modules); you can access their [`__dict__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__), or better still, use the [`vars()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars), to treat their namespace as a dictionary:

```
>>> import string
>>> list(vars(string))
['whitespace', '_string', 'ChainMap', 'ascii_uppercase', 'digits', '__name__', 'punctuation', 'Formatter', 'Template', '__doc__', '__spec__', '_re', 'hexdigits', '__package__', 'ascii_lowercase', '__cached__', 'octdigits', 'ascii_letters', '__builtins__', '_TemplateMetaclass', '__file__', 'capwords', '__loader__', 'printable']
```